# spring mvc ajax json malformed sometimes

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, spring

**libraries used**

1. spring.4.3.4 jar
2. jquery 1.9.1
3. gson-2.2.2 jar

Using JDBCTemplate

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user/getApmcBudgTransData", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public @ResponseBody String getUserLevelMasterDetails(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse res) { 
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        String yrmstid=request.getParameter("finyrMstid");
        String apmcid=request.getParameter("apmcid");
        String sendToOfc = request.getParameter("sendToOfc");   
        String opFlag = request.getParameter("opFlag"); 
        String formType = request.getParameter("formType"); 
        ArrayList<ApmcBudgTransaction> apmcBudgtrandata=budgetService.getApmcBudgTransData(apmcid, yrmstid, sendToOfc, opFlag, formType);       

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(apmcBudgtrandata);
    }
```

**JSP ajax call**

```
                  $.ajax({
                    url:"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/getApmcBudgTransData",
                    type:'post',  
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async:false,
                    data: {
                        finyrMstid :lastyr,
                        apmcid : pkvalue,
                        sendToOfc : "APMC",
                        opFlag : flag,
                        formType : "S"
                     },
                   success: function(resp) {},
                   error: function(err) {}

                   });
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.me.you" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />


    <mvc:interceptors>


    <bean id="webContentInterceptor" 
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
    </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>



</beans>
```

The ajax call is receiving a large amout of utf-8 json data from controller.

The json is wellformed in the controller each and every time.

When the control is returned back to ajax call, the first time, the json is malformed and error function is called.

The second and each subsequent time though, the json is wellformed and success function is called.

**Firebug screenshot**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwG6B.jpg

**Malformed json**

```
   [
  {
    "finYrID": "3",
    "budgetTransId": "18127210",
    "operationId": "",
    "commonTrno": "165",
    "suppliBudgYn": "N",
    "tranDate": "10/05/2016",
    "srNo": "1",
    "apmcGlMstId": "1",
    "apmcMstId": "165",
    "lastYrActualAmt": "2741406",
    "currYrActualAmt": "2562",
    "currYrExpAmt": "0",
    "currYrTotExpAmt": "2562",
    "apmcCurrBudgAmt": "2379",
    "disCurrBudgAmt": "2379",
    "divCurrBudgAmt": "2379",
    "apmcRemark": "",
    "distRemark": "",
    "divRemark": "",
    "msambRemark": "शिफारस आहे",
    "sanctionRemark": "",
    "suppBudAmt": "0",
    "suppDistBudgAmount": "",
    "suppDivBudgAmount": "",
    "suppHoBudgetAmt": "",
    "suppBudgetRemark": "",
    "suppDisRemark": "",
    "suppDivRemark": "",
    "suppHoRemark": "",
    "suppSancRemark": "",
    "printPosition": "",
    "forwardStatus": "P",
    "lastYrBudgamt": "3035810",
    "msambCurYrBudgAmt": "2379",
    "glName": "सुरवातीची रोख शिल्लक ",
    "abrxFlg": "INCOME",
    "parentId": "",
    "allowEntry": "Y",
    "apmcTranDate": "12/05/2016",
    "distTranDate": "24/05/2016",
    "divTranDate": "06/06/2016",
    "hoTranDate": "19/07/2016",
    "sanctionDate": "20/09/2016",
    "docAppFlag": "",
    "suppBudgTrno": "100165",
    "apmcSuppTranDate": "",
    "distSuppTranDate": "",
    "divSuppTranDate": "",
    "hoSuppTranDate": "",
    "sancSuppDate": "",
    "suppDocAppFlag": "Y",
    "budgSendToOffice": "SANCTION",
    "suppSendToOffice": "APMC",
    "suppCurYrActualAmt": "2379",
    "suppCurYrExpectedAmt": "0",
    "suppCurYrTotExpectedAmt": "2379"
  },
  {
    "finYrID": "3",
    "budgetTransId": "18127209",
    "operationId": "",
    "commonTrno": "165",
    "suppliBudgYn": "N",
    "tranDate": "10/05/2016",
    "srNo": "181",
    "apmcGlMstId": "181",
    "apmcMstId": "165",
    "lastYrActualAmt": "0",
    "currYrActualAmt": "0",
    "currYrExpAmt": "304852",
    "currYrTotExpAmt": "304852",
    "apmcCurrBudgAmt": "438307",
    "disCurrBudgAmt": "1238307",
    "divCurrBudgAmt": "1148307",
    "apmcRemark": "",
    "distRemark": "898751.00",
    "divRemark": "",
    "msambRemark": "",
    "sanctionRemark": "",
    "suppBudAmt": "315514",
    "suppDistBudgAmount": "0",
    "suppDivBudgAmount": "0",
    "suppHoBudgetAmt": "0",
    "suppBudgetRemark": "",
    "suppDisRemark": "",
    "suppDivRemark": "",
    "suppHoRemark": "",
    "suppSancRemark": "",
    "printPosition": "",
    "forwardStatus": "P",
    "lastYrBudgamt": "0",
    "msambCurYrBudgAmt": "898751",
    "glName": "अखेरची बँक शिल्लक ",
    "abrxFlg": "EXPENSES",
    "parentId": "",
    "allowEntry": "Y",
    "apmcTranDate": "12/05/2016",
    "distTranDate": "24/05/2016",
    "divTranDate": "06/06/2016",
    "hoTranDate": "19/07/2016",
    "sanctionDate": "20/09/2016",
    "docAppFlag": "",
    "suppBudgTrno": "100165",
    "apmcSuppTranDate": "",
    "distSuppTranDate": "",
    "divSuppTranDate": "",
    "hoSuppTranDate": "",
    "sancSuppDate": "",
    "suppDocAppFlag": "Y",
    "budgSendToOffice": "SANCTION",
    "suppSendToOffice": "APMC",
    "suppCurYrActualAmt": "957593",
    "suppCurYrExpectedAmt": "",
    "suppCurYrTotExpectedAmt": "957593"
  }
]
```

I cannot for the love of programming figure out why this is happening.

Comment: First of all, why you are converting to string using gson. Dont you think it is complicated as spring mvc going to use one of the httpmessageconverters anyway ?

Comment: I removed gson. Now I am getting:- java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.forType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter;    I have added jackson-databind-2.7.3.jar, core and annotation jars to the classpath as well. I tried removing older jackson-asl jars but still the same error.