# spring jackson ObjectWriter forType no such method

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

spring 4.3.4
jackson 2.8.6

In tomcat 9, jackson databind, core and annotations jar are working properly with spring 4.3.4 but in wildfly 8, I get

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.forType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter;

I had posted the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996241/spring-mvc-ajax-json-malformed-sometimes)

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996241/spring-mvc-ajax-json-malformed-sometimes#comment71178157_41996241)

Comment: You most likely have an older version of Jackson somewhere in Tomcat's classpath. the `forType` method was introduced in Jackson 2.5, so look for an older version. :)

Comment: I have jackson-core-asl.jar and jackson-mapper-asl.jar in my class path as well as we recently upgraded to Spring 4. Should I remove the older jackson jars?

Comment: I removed the older versions of jackson but still the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Even i was also getting same error in Wildfly 8.2.0 due to older jar(Which was using 2.4.0 by default).

***Fixed as below.***

Download latest version of jacksont-*.jar, i've downloaded stable version i.e. 2.9.0


a. jackson-annotations-2.9.0

b. jackson-databind-2.9.0

c. jackson-core-2.9.0

Then go-to {wildfly_server}/modules/system/layers/base/com/fasterxml/jackson/core

**a. change respective module.xml to 2.9.0, in /jackson-

/main/ folder.

b. Copy the downloaded jars to {wildfly_server}/modules/system/layers/base/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-

/main/**

That's all. Now restart the server.